# Include colouring in GNU ls time-style

Tags: terminal, ls

I know, I can specify custom time format for `ls` like this

```
ls -lAF --time-style="+ %Y-%b-%d  %H:%M:%S" --color=always
```

but I would like to "smuggle in" colors inside the time format. For example, I would like to have the year `2014` in red color. How would I do that?

I have tried putting the color code `\033[0;31m` in front of the `%Y`, but the code does not get interpreted as color but as gibberish.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Enter the ESC character literally. This is usually done by entering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then the requested key, in this case <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Or in `ksh93`, `zsh` or `bash`, use the `$'...'` quotes where `echo`-like escape sequences are expanded:

```
ls -lAF --time-style=$'+ \e[31m%Y\e[m-%b-%d  %H:%M:%S' --color=always
```